# SQLAlchemy MySQL Caching?

Tags: mysql, caching, sqlalchemy

I am developing an intense financial MySQL database (django + SQLAlchemy) which is interrogated and manipulated constantly. My DB contains a lot of date-value pairs. I keep loading more and more data as time progresses, but historical values don't change which is why I think caching could really improve performance for me.

Is beaker really my best option, or should I implement my own caching over Redis? I would love to hear some ideas for caching architectures - thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788051/497208 an be useful

Answer (score 0):

The [Mysql cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) stores the text of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was sent to the client.

If an identical statement is received later, the server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing and executing the statement again. The query cache is shared among sessions, so a result set generated by one client can be sent in response to the same query issued by another client.

Comment: hey - thank you for your response. I definitely the the query cache will be helpful, however since I am dealing with data addition many times a minute (remember, we're talking about things like stock quotes - the data table grows all the table, and therefore the data would be stale of its cached with the query cache), I feel like implementing a custom caching mechanism would boost performance greatly. What other solutions should I be looking at? thanks!