# How to turn off MySQL query cache while using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am working with a fairly large MySQL database via the SQLAlchemy library, and I'd love to turn off MySQL's query caching to debug performance issues on a per-session basis. It's difficult to debug slow queries when repeating them results in much faster execution. With the CLI MySQL client, I can execute `SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF;` to achieve the result I'm looking for, and I would like to run this on every SQLAlchemy session (when I'm debugging).

But I can't figure out how to configure SQLAlchemy such that it runs `SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF` when it instantiates a new database session.

I've looked at the [Engine and Connection docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options), but can't seem to find anything.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing, or a better way of doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788051/497208 can be useful

Answer (score 6):

Use an [event hook](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/core/events.html) immediately after you define your engine:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def disable_query_cache(conn, record):
    conn.cursor().execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF")


# this is probably in your Pyramid setup code
engine = create_engine(...)

if DEBUGGING:
    event.listen(engine, 'connect', disable_query_cache)
```

You can do this globally by adding the hook to the `Pool` class itself, but (a) you probably want the Pyramid settings available anyway so you can decide whether or not to add the hook, and (b) global state is bad :)