# Not able to get latest rows when re-rerunning same query at regular interval

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using Python MySQLdb module. I am querying a table every 1 seconds. New rows are being added to this table all the time. The code is as follows;

```
def main(): 
    connectMySqlDb_tagem()

    while True:
        queryTable()
        time.sleep(1)

        closeDBconnection()
```

The problem with the code is that the query does not return the latest rows. It always return the same rows. To solve this problem, I have to close the MySQL connection and make a new MySQL connection everytime. The workable code looks like this;

```
def main(): 

    while True:
        connectMySqlDb_tagem()
        queryTable()
        closeDBconnection() 
        time.sleep(1)
```

How can I avoid making a new connection everytime in order to get the latest rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) in your `SELECT` query, or turn it off on a session level:

```
cursor.execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF")
```

See also:

- [How to turn off MySQL query cache while using SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372760/how-to-turn-off-mysql-query-cache-while-using-sqlalchemy)
- [MySQL - force not to use cache for testing speed of query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181894/mysql-force-not-to-use-cache-for-testing-speed-of-query)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
connection.commit()
```

instead of disconnecting and reconnecting and see if it solves your problem.