# Sqlalchemy returns "stale" rows?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table (MySQL) with a row in it.

I can read it fine with:

```
self._session.query(Automatic).\
             filter(Automatic.do_when <= time()).\
             limit(limit).\
             all()
```

However, if I then delete the row from table (with the mysql client or phpMyAdmin), the row is still returned by the code above. I don't know if this is related to the question "[How to disable SQLAlchemy caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210080/how-to-disable-sqlalchemy-caching)".

Edit:
Adding a

```
self._session.commit()
```

after makes no difference.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed related to the question to which you have linked; as the top-rated (and accepted) answer states, you need to `session.commit()` your transaction.

Comment: @eggyal, so even a read operation is a transaction? I put a session.commit() after the code above. No cigar.

Comment: No, you need to commit the delete operation; as that answer also explains, any other transactions which began before the commit operation will still see the unmodified data due to MySQL's (default) consistent read isolation level.

Comment: But phpmyadmin has autocommit right?  @eggyal  I also run the statement again *well* after the row was deleted in phpmyadmin. (Many seconds.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were performing the `DELETE` from outside of sqlalchemy; yes, it will be committed.  Your problem lies in the fact that the read operation is occurring within a transaction that began before the `DELETE` operation was committed and (due to the isolation level) cannot see the changes that have occurred since.  You could, for example, commit before the read operation in order to begin a fresh transaction upon a then-current snapshot.

Comment: @eggyal, so commit *before* reading?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit: Adding commit() before reading did the trick, as per [eggyal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal) explanation.

```
self._session.commit()
self._session.query(Automatic).\
             filter(Automatic.do_when <= time()).\
             limit(limit).\
             all()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This also worked for me, though I don't know if I should rejoice or cry.

Comment: Worked! It's really wired that you need to do this... I migrate my db from postgres to mysql and encountered this issue. Previously in postgres you didn't need to do that...