# Isolation level with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble understanding how database isolation levels work with Flask-SQLAlchemy, and especially how to **really** commit changes or close a session. Here is the context of my problem :

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy for a Flask project with a MySQL database.
Here is how is configured my project

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user:passwd@localhost/mydb'
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = '/path/to/myapp/db_repository'

CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'this is a secret'
```

The creation of the `db` object in my `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I have defined models such as `Printer` one:

```
from myapp import db
...
class Printer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I tried to play around with a python terminal, and even though I read about the `Read committed` isolation level of SQLAlchemy, I face the following problem. Here is what I have in my console:

```
>>> from myapp import app
>>> from myapp.models import Printer
>>> import config
>>> from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>> app.config.from_object('config')
>>> db = SQLAlchemy(app)
>>> for printer in Printer.query.all():
...     print printer.name
...
Circle
Mww
>>> p = Printer('dummy')
>>> db.session.add(p)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> for printer in Printer.query.all():
...     print printer.name
...
Circle
Mww
>>>
```

When I look up the database, my change has been committed :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM printer;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Circle |
|  2 | Mww    |
|  3 | dummy  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I quit my python terminal, open it again and just read the results with Printer.query.all(), my changes appear.

Though I understand SQLAlchemy waits for change to be committed and/or the session to be closed, I don't get why I can't read my changes after the `db.session.commit()` statement nor how to close the session (I tried `db.session.close()`, reading the database after that does not give better results)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens if you use the SQLAlchemy version of the query?

```
db.session.query(Printer).all()
```

I'm wondering if there are two sessions going on:

1. The one your app sets up that `Printer.query.all()` is talking to
2. The one you're using in that snippet that you created by that `db = SQLAlchemy()` call

It would explain why the `db.session.commit()` isn't flushing the data that `Printer.query.all()` has.

Comment: You made my day. Still, I'd like to really understand what happens here : setting the `db` object creates a session, and any request created from the Model.query function creates other concurrent sessions?

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad. And yes, that's right. If you look at the setup docs (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html), notice that you create db = SQLAlchemy() and then your models inherit from db.Model. When you call MyModel.query.all() it uses that session. You created a new session (entirely fine) but they don't automatically talk. I believe you can tell SQLAlchemy to manually expire caches, though, but I don't know that command offhand. The docs probably have it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I'll get through the docs.
Impressive CV btw, inspiring for us students!

Comment: I am facing exact same issue on flask server running on EC2. whereas its working fine on my local machine. Dodn't worked even after expiring the session like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21917724/5167801. 
Did you made it work ?

Comment: UPDATE: My issue was, I was running flask app with guniwork webserver using 3 workers, and cache was not same for all three workers. Reducing them to 1 resolved.