# why flask sqlalchemy model query does not get newest records?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Model class:

```
class PlatformUsage(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'platform_usage'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    module = db.Column(db.String(64))
    rb = db.Column(db.BigInteger)
    status = db.Column(db.String(64))
    platform = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def __init__(self, module, rb, status, platform):
        self.module = module
        self.rb = rb
        self.status = status
        self.platform = platform

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<PlatformUsage(module: %s, rb: %d, status: %s, platform: %s>" % (
           self.module, self.rb, self.status, self.platform)
```

when i query like this:

```
while True:
  PlatformUsage.query.filter_by(module='xxx')
```

I change the db externally, I can not get the newest results!  why ?

```
session.query(PlatformUsage).filter_by(xxxx)
```

will get the correct result!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285474/how-to-disable-caching-correctly-in-sqlalchemy-orm-session

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa   the link seems not solve my problem....

Comment: Please see this post to understand why the model query doesn't work as expected: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024302/isolation-level-with-flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question Mikko Ohtamaa links to doesn't immediately answer your question, but contains what you need to know to understand.

After the first time you execute a query you are in a transaction. Within the transactions most DBMS guarantee you repeatable read (or give you that option). I.e. each time you run a query within a transaction *you will get the same answer*. That is what is happening when you execute the first code.

On the scond one you probably hit F5 on the browser and you get a new transaction. That gives you the newest data.

Comment: is there a way to get new result without explicit use a session each time?

Comment: Just try to change transaction isolation level to READ_COMMITTED http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-isolation-level