# Flask SQLAlchemy doesn't fetch new added rows until server restart

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a **Python Flask** application with **Flask-SQLAlchemy**. when new data gets inserted to the db, it doesn't get fetched unless I restart the server.

#### view_function

```
from models import dataObj

@app.route('/view-data/')
def view_data():
    objs = dataObj.query.order_by(dataObj.added_date.desc()).all()
    return render_template("view_data.html", objs=objs)
```

#### add_data_function

```
data_obj = dataObj("data")
db.session.add(data_obj)
db.session.commit()
```

#### view_data.html

```
{% if objs %}
    {% for obj in objs %}
        {{obj.data}}
    {% endfor %}
{%endif%}
```

Is there some caching in play ?

Comment: I do have a similar problem, did u find a way to handle this problem ?

Comment: @AlirezaAyinMehr I don't remember much about this project I'm afraid.

Comment: @DarkSuniuM has anyone of you find solution to this problem i have similar problem.

Comment: @ADWAN I did fixed my problem by using `db.sessionmaker(autoflush=True)`, Check if it fixes the problem

Comment: @DarkSuniuM thanks for the response am trying to do with `sqlite3` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Answered on similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986875/why-flask-sqlalchemy-model-query-does-not-get-newest-records)